# ios Cutom tableview cell subview each other overlaping each other

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have created two custom cells with **UILabel** and **UIImageView**.
Even if I added space between them the UIImageView cell overlaps with the UILabel cell. In addition, I am updating the frame of the UIlabel cell but its not updating. I am not using autolayout. Can any one give me solution for this?

[image]

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetermineCoatingCell *cell=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetermineCoatingCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
    float cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *option =[arrOptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (is_iPad) {
        // float yValue=(cellHeight/2)-10;
        lblTable= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 5, 590, cellHeight)];
        lblTable.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
        lblTable.numberOfLines=0;
        lblTable.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:63.0/255.0f green:126.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        lblTable.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;    
    } else {
        // float yValue=(cellHeight/2)-5;
        if (![option[@"CoatingImage"] isEqualToString:@""]) {    
            cell.imgView.tag = indexPath.row;
            cell.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgViewTapped:)];
            tapgesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;              
            tapgesture.view.tag = indexPath.row;
            tapgesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            //  [tapgesture setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row] forKey:@"Tag"];

           [cell.imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];

            NSString *key = [[option valueForKey:@"CoatingImage"] MD5Hash];
            NSData *data = [FTWCache objectForKey:key];
            if (data) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                cell.imageView.image=image; 
            } else {              
                [WebImageOperations processImageDataWithURLString:[option valueForKey:@"CoatingImage"] andBlock:^(NSData *imageData) {

                    [FTWCache setObject:imageData forKey:key];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        cell.imageView.image=image;
                    });          
                }];
            }
        } else { 
            CGRect framelbl  = CGRectMake(0,0, cell.lblTitle.frame.size.width,cell.lblTitle.frame.size.height);

            NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(framelbl));
            [cell.lblTitle setFrame:framelbl];
        }
    }
    cell.lblTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[option valueForKey:@"AnswerOptionText" ]];

    cell.lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor  colorWithRed:63.0/255.0f green:126.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];

    NSLog(@"lblTableText %@",lblTable.text);

    if(selectedPath.row == indexPath.row  && selectedPath.section == indexPath.section)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:227.0/255.0f green:227.0/255.0f blue:227.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];;
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show us the layout code in your cell subclass to place the image and label. Also where were the frames set?

Comment: If you use autolayout you are not supposed and/or allowed to change the frame manually!

Comment: i am not using autolayout. @luk2302

Comment: where is your code about "added space between them "?

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined not to use autolayout in the table view, then investigate the table view delegate method -[id tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

You'll need to identify which row corresponds to an image view cell, and which to a label cell, and then return the appropriate height.